# Segmentation fault / fail to boot after CPU upgrade?

Tags: boot, server, segmentation-fault, intel-cpu

My machine is a HP ProDesk 400 G4 SFF running Ubuntu Server 20.04.

It was running just fine with the original Intel i5-6500 CPU, but upon upgrading to an i7-6700 the system will no longer boot.

I've tried entering rescue mode and emergency mode, but neither of them will actually boot the system. Any ideas?

**EDIT:** I'm unable to boot from install media on a USB drive either. Here is a screenshot of a failed boot:

[image: segmentation fault]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**ramdisk**

Your ramdisk file is not current for your new CPU.

From the GRUB menu, boot to Recovery Mode...

- GRUB menu

  - Additional Options

    - Recovery Mode

      - Root Access

And type:

`sudo update-initramfs -c -k $(uname -r)`

`reboot`

**BIOS**

HP ProDesk 400 G4 Small Form Factor PC

You currently have BIOS version P08 2.15, from Jan 30, 2018.

There's a newer BIOS available, version P08 02.35 Rev.A, from May 11, 2020, and can be downloaded [here](https://support.hp.com/us-en/drivers/selfservice/hp-prodesk-400-g4-small-form-factor-pc/15292380).

Note: Confirm that I have the correct web page for your model #.

Note: Have good backups before updating the BIOS.

**memtest**

Go to https://www.memtest86.com/ and download/run their free `memtest` to test your memory. Get at least one complete pass of all the 4/4 tests to confirm good memory. This may take many hours to complete.

**Update #1:**

`memtest` fails at test #6 [Block Move], with i7, and either 8G or 32G RAM installed. Same address range. Suspect CPU or motherboard problem.

**Update #2:**

It was determined that the (used) i7 CPU was defective. The i5 CPU was reinstalled, and memtest ran fine again.

Comment: I've actually tried to get into recovery mode from grub with new CPU fitted - no dice :( 

The screenshot that I included was from an attempt to boot from the Server 20.04 install media, so surely my ramdisk shouldn't prevent the installer from starting? 

I'll try updating the BIOS and report back. 

Memtest was successfully run a few months ago when the RAM was fitted.

Comment: @Dalarielus  Can you not boot to a Ubuntu Live DVD/USB? If not, on another system, do part 3 of my answer... and build a memtest flash, and check your RAM on this system.

Comment: @Dalarielus Is your CPU or RAM overclocked?

Comment: I've tried booting from the Ubuntu Server 20.04 install media from a USB flash disk (the same disk that I used to originally install Ubuntu onto this system) and it fails with segmentation faults and a kernel panic. Memtest is currently running with the RAM transplanted into another system, but I'm not expecting any faults since it was known to be good a couple of months ago and the system booted normally after swapping the old CPU back into it. The CPU and RAM are both running at stock speeds and haven't been overclocked.

Comment: @Dalarielus Oh, you really need to **run memtest with the RAM in the original machine with i7**, assuming that the memtest flash will boot there.

Comment: D'oh! I'll try that and report back. If it passes, I'll try updating the BIOS.

Comment: @Dalarielus Status please...

Comment: Sorry for the delayed response - work has been challenging recently. The plot thickens! With the i7 memtest86 is failing on test 6 but with no other errors prior to that. When I get time I'll be swapping out the RAM for a known good stick and trying again. It would also be interesting to see the results of memtest86 with the i5, because I find it hard to believe that the system would boot with the i5 if the RAM really was as bad as it seems to behave with the i7. A quick Google is showing other people failing on test 6 and it turning out to be a bad CPU.

Comment: @Dalarielus If you haven't updated the BIOS yet, do that first, then rerun memtest.

Comment: @Dalarielus If my answer was helpful, please remember to accept it by clicking on the checkmark icon that appears just to the left of my answer. Thanks!

Comment: I actually updated the BIOS before running memtest. I've just run it again with the i7 and different RAM - memtest fails at the exact same point. This is starting to look more like a CPU problem than anything else. Here are the results of [memtest with the i7 and 32GB RAM](https://imgur.com/a/bLzBjWp) and here are the results of [memtest with the i7 and 8GB RAM](https://imgur.com/a/2TcYIMy). I guess the next step is to swap the i5 back in and run memtest again?

Comment: @Dalarielus Good on the BIOS update. The memtest fails at the same addresses, no matter which RAM you have installed, and it's picking a bit. Do you have more than one memory slot available? If so, try another slot and retest. Possible CPU or motherboard problem.

Comment: @Dalarielus Show me `sudo lshw -C memory`.

Comment: Status please...

Comment: @Dalarielus Status please...

Comment: Update: It was definitely the CPU. Upon reinstalling the i5, memtest was successful (all tests, all passes) on both sets of RAM. Thanks for all the help!

Comment: @Dalarielus Thanks for the update! Are you going to be able to do a warranty replacement on the i7?

Comment: Unfortunately not, as it was purchased used. I'll definitely be taking it up with the seller though!